# How to perform Average

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I do have the below code where it gives me the sum of **Sales** and **Profit** based on **Country** and **State**.

```
import pandas as pd

Order = pd.read_excel (r"C:\Users\Sample.xls", sheet_name='Orders')
Return = pd.read_excel (r"C:\Users\Sample.xls", sheet_name='Returns')

Order.merge(Return, on='Order ID', how='inner')\
    .groupby(['Country', 'State']).agg(Sales=("Sales", sum),Profit=("Profit", sum)).reset_index()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

My Requirement is I want to calculate **Average Sales** and formulae for **Average Sales** is **Average Sales=sum of sales/count of states**. For example for state **Arizona** I have 22 rows so the Average Sales if **6015.773/22 = 273.444227272727**.

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Use `avg_Sales=("Sales", 'mean')`

Comment: No worries got that now